# Django and Elasticbeanstalk: a column that has been deleted on local hasn't been deleted on RDS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed my project into eb and a form submission doesn't work on eb even though it works on local. And I found the cause.
One of the attribute of a model that is not allowed to be null still remains on RDS even though I removed it in the past.

Log error is like this

```
ERROR:  null value in column "a_variable" violates not-null constraint
```

How can I handle with this problem? Is there a way to remove the column manually on RDS? I am using `PostgreSQL` as the db engine.

Comment: did you run all migrations? that should have removed the column

Comment: Yes ofc I did..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RDS database is just a normal PostgreSQL database. If you really need to access it directly, you can:

- Create a security group to open up the PostgreSQL port (5432 with TCP) to your current IP address.
- Add the security group to your RDS instance (temporarily, don't forget to remove it later)
- Use psql on your local machine to connect to your RDS instance, with your django credentials.
- Run the normal SQL command (`ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name;`) to delete the column. Be careful! you're directly manipulating your database.

To be sure I would check the django-migrations table to see if all migrations were run correctly. you might run into problems with later migrations if that isn't the case.

Comment: I still cannot connect to the db.. What does adding security group mean? The security group is already included in the instance.

Comment: I posted my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311978/aws-rds-and-pgadmin4-unable-to-connect-to-server-could-not-connect-to-server Could you see it?

Comment: Actually I think I know the cause of this error. I actually deleted all migration files and recreated the db on local in the past and before recreating the db, I deleted this attribute and then recreate. So my current migration file cannot tell AWS I deleted the column and it still remains. Do you think it is still safe to recreate  the db (including the deleted attribute) on local again and delete the attribute so migration file can record it?

Comment: it's always a bad idea to delete migration files if you've already applied them in a production environment because then you don't have the same starting point anymore. When modifying any migration that was already applied you need to be super careful and really know what you're doing (`manage.py migrate --fake` can help). If you're currently in a situation where the code works and `manage.py migrate` doesn't produce errors on production after you've updated your code to the latest commit, I wouldn't touch the migrations.

Comment: I did it. My website was fixed. Thanks a lot.