# AWS RDS and pgAdmin4 : Unable to connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to manipulate db directly from pgAdmin4 but I cannot connect.

What I checked and did are

I read this doc and following
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html#USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.Troubleshooting

and input the information about the db instance as the doc does.

[image]

However I couldn't connect and I checked the security group.
The VPC security group is like this.

[image: this]

What else should I check? I totally have no idea how I can fix this.
The only concern is the password's current value is always going to be empty even after I set a password.

[image]

Anyone could help me? I have to connect and manipulate db directly.

Comment: as source address, what did you put? you should look up your public IP address (whatismyipaddress.com) followed by /32 (e.g. 90.145.94.10/32). As username/password you should use the ones you have in settings.py, not something you setup in AWS console. As database, same thing, it should be the `NAME` you have in settings.py (probably not postgres).

Comment: You need an extra security group. The default security group allows the servers (elastic bean instances) inside your VPC to connect to your RDS. The new security group should allow your laptop/desktop PC that's sitting in front of you to connect to it. The default security group doesn't allow that (which is good, so no one outside the VPC can access your database). Create a new security group, add it **and remove it when you're finished**.

Comment: Ahh I see.. I totally misunderstood.. I will try it.

Comment: oh and one little advice: if the data in your RDS is important, do yourself a favour and take a snapshot of it just before you start manipulating anything. Then at least you have a backup.

Comment: @dirkgroten  Sorry for asking question again. I wanted to ask just in case. So for host name, I can set the RDS instance's host name? I set `HOSTNAME` in `setting.py` as well but it isn't unique name.

Comment: Your hostname looks correct yes. What do you mean it’s not unique?

Comment: @dirkgroten There is no difference between default SG and custom SG (if they have the same rules). What you have said about default SG is completely incorrect.

Comment: I suggested to create a new SG rather than editing the default SG (adding a new rule to it) because it’s less prone to break things if you’re a beginner to AWS. That’s what I said. I think you misinterpreted my statement. When I said “doesn’t allow that” I didn’t mean doesn’t allow you to add a rule, I meant is configured to not allow access from outside

Comment: @dirkgroten In that case, you are right.

Comment: @dirkgroten I mean I set `HOSTNAME` as an environment variavble but it's not the same as the instance's name.

Comment: @dirkgroten Hi I finally did it and my website was fixed thanks a lot. I have a question. Is is danger not to remove the new rule that allows to access from my laptop?

Comment: Not a big danger, but IP addresses change (your ISP might change it) and then that address could be anyone. Better to add it each time you need it.

Comment: I see. I got it.

Answer (score 7):

**You need to create a new Security Group Inbound Rules**

- Go to "Security group rules" (under "Connectivity & security")
- Click the item "default" Security group
- Click "Actions" > "Edit inbound rules" > "Add rule"
- Select... Type: "All traffic", Source: "My IP", then click "Save rules"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to  this steps,
You need to create a new Security Group Inbound Rules

Go to "Security group rules" (under "Connectivity & security")
Click the item "default" Security group
Click "Actions" > "Edit inbound rules" > "Add rule"
Select... Type: "All traffic", Source: "My IP", then click "Save rules"

select the default maintenance db as postgres instead of your amazon db instance name